# How to sorting within same date data based on time in google sheet using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to sort data based on date(Column A) and start time(Column I). If date column have more than 1 same date then again shorting by start time within this same date contain rows.

i have a code already that sorting by date.

```
function autoSort() {
  var headerRows = 1;
  var sortFirst = 1; // 1 is Column "A"
  var sortFirstAsc = false; // When it's "true", the order is ascending.
  var sortSecond = 9; // 3 is Column "C"
  var sortSecondAsc = false; // When it's "true", the order is ['OPEN','YES','NO'].

  // Retrieve values from Spreadsheet.
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = activeSheet.getSheetName(); //name of sheet to be sorted
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var range = sheet.getRange(headerRows+1, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-headerRows, sheet.getLastColumn());
  var values = range.getValues();

  // Sort the date of column "A".
  var s1 = sortFirstAsc ? 1 : -1;
  values.sort(function(a, b) {return (a[sortFirst - 1] < b[sortFirst - 1] ? -s1 : s1)});

  // Sort the values of column "C" with the custom sort using the keys.
  var sortOrder = ['OPEN','YES','NO'];
  var s2 = sortSecondAsc ? 1 : -1;
  values.sort(function(a, b) {
    var i1 = sortOrder.indexOf(a[sortSecond - 1]);
    var i2 = sortOrder.indexOf(b[sortSecond - 1]);
    var vlen =  values.length;
    return s2 * ((i1 > -1 ? i1 : vlen) - (i2 > -1 ? i2 : vlen));
  });
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: I would have chosen to use a single datetime object and then it's just a matter of subtracting datetime valueOf() or getTime().  So if you are getting you date and time from a single datetime object then use it to sort your data

Comment: Why not simply use the menu Sort?  Or if you want this to run from, let say onEdit(), then Range.sort().  You say its by date and then time.

Comment: Can you provide a copy of your spreadsheet, free of sensitive information?